# Automatically adding html in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am making use of the `{% extends 'core/base.html %}` tag to include a header. I write this on the beginning line of each page I create so that it loads a navigation bar and other static files. Is there a way to not write the extends functionality on each page I create and instead it is injected automatically each time I create a page?

Comment: This is a bad idea. What is the problem with being explicit? It is just **one line** when you are writing `{% extends 'core/base.html %}` (honestly complaining about writing one line is a bit too much, why not just create a template or something in your IDE which automatically does this if you really want something like so), your suggestion of doing such things automatically is just going to confuse people later on. They won't know where the remaining HTML is coming from, plus what if they want to extend some _other template_ instead of this one?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the reason I ask is because I am trying to build a single page application. When I load a new page within the same page, that new page also has the extends and is loading in the static files again